# Install Java 1.7 OpenJDK in another directory

Tags: java, linux, installation, rpm

I need to install Java 1.7 OpenJDK in `/opt/java1.7` directory.

When I run `whereis java` it still shows that it's installed in `/usr/bin/java` and I need it to be `/opt/java1.7/`.

Comment: Why does it matter ? How do you install it ? Have you thought of using a symlink ?

Comment: It might already be there. On my system, `realpath /usr/bin/java` prints `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java`

Comment: Search for other installations with find / -name java

Answer (score 0):

Let the system's package manager (`yum`, `apt-get`; assuming you are running some Linux distro) install it wherever it defaults to.

Then create a symlink with:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64 /opt/java1.7
```

(using the paths you indicated in the comment to your question).

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem not mentioned by OP is that Java7 is considered obsolete; Java8 has been current since last spring.  So, in the background we might assume that OP wants to put Java7 in a directory under `/opt` named for the given version.

It would be nice if the OpenJDK package were relocatable.  The possibility of relocatable packages is mentioned here and there:

- [Relocatable packages](http://rpm.org/api/4.4.2.2/relocatable.html)
- [How to install RPM packages in a different location?](http://www.mysqlab.net/knowledge/kb/detail/topic/installation/id/8409)
- [How do I install an RPM package into a different directory?](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-install-rpm-package-into-another-directory/)

It is not: I was curious, and tried using the `--installroot` option of `dnf` ("same" as `yum`, but again, the latter is deprecated on Fedora22).

If you install Java7 on a system where you already have Java8, your package system may change the symbolic links for `/usr/bin/java` and/or `/etc/alternatives/java` to point to the newest install of Java.

Aside from that, it seems that the various systems where you might want to install OpenJDK have packaged it to avoid conflict.

With Fedora, for instance, the package `java-1.7.0-openjdk-headless` contains Java7's JRE.  (If you need the development package, that would be `java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel`):

- [RPM resource java-1.7.0-openjdk](https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=java-1.7.0-openjdk)
- [RPM resource java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel](https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel)

As suggested, you *could* make a symbolic link from `/opt` to the location in `/usr/lib/jvm` where your Java resides.  Your `PATH` would have to have `/opt/java1.7/bin` and/or `/opt/java1.7/jre/bin`, depending on whether you want the development- or runtime-packages.

You should not construct the symbolic link in a manner that would eliminate the `/bin` leaf.  The reason for this is that the executables are built using the *rpath* option so that the linker can find the required Java shared library based on the location of the executable.  Incidentally, that is *why* the symbolic link works.  Doing `objdump -axh` on the `java` executable shows (among other things) something like this:

```
Dynamic Section:
  NEEDED               libpthread.so.0
  NEEDED               libz.so.1
  NEEDED               libjli.so
  NEEDED               libdl.so.2
  NEEDED               libc.so.6
  SONAME               lib.so
  RPATH                $ORIGIN/../lib/amd64/jli:$ORIGIN/../lib/amd64
```

Because of this use of *rpath*, it would be possible to *move* the entire directory from `/usr/lib/jvm` to `/opt` and rename it in that location.  Doing this has the drawback that package updates would not work, but it would succeed in "installing" Java7 *in* that location.